# Prevent user from using the token and making service request

Tags: javascript, rest, jwt

I am using web tokens. User can see the request and response from server. SO he can see the request and token inside the request. So he can open up an ARC/postman and make server requests for data or he can use CURL to get data also. Can this be avoided? Is there a way by which token misuse can be prevented?

Comment: If you don't want the user to use the token, don't give it to them.  Why do you want to prevent them from using curl?  How is using the token to access a service, a service to which they presumably are supposed to have access (hence the token), misusing that token?

Comment: Use HTTPS/SSL to secure communication between the server and the client. Except for the host server information any data will be encrypted and only be visible either at the server or the client machine. If you fear a reuse of the token on the client machine by an other process/user/intruder, a token based access may not be the best choice anyway.